# Name of particular graph theory vertex cover

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

Given a graph $G$ with vertex set $V$, what is the name of a vertex cover $V'$ such that all vertices in $V$ are either in $V'$ or adjacent to a vertex in $V'$? (Is this type of cover even already defined? It's been years since I've thought hard about graph theory.) For a particular graph, I'm looking for a minimally sized cover of this type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [vertex cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover) is already a technical term. A set $V' \subseteq V$ is a vertex cover if every *edge* of the graph has at least one endpoint of $V'$.

If you mean "what is the name for a vertex cover with the additional property that every vertex is either an element of $V'$ or has a neighbor in $V'$?" then there is no name for this concept, but it's very close to just a vertex cover. If the graph has no isolated vertices, then every vertex cover already has this property: if $V'$ is a vertex cover and $v$ is a vertex outside $V'$, then let $vw$ be any edge out of $v$; it must be covered by $V'$, so we must have $w \in V'$, and therefore $v$ has a neighbor in $V'$.

If the graph has isolated vertices, then such a vertex cover is just any vertex cover that contains all of those isolated vertices.

---

If you did not mean the term "vertex cover" in its technical sense, and you're just looking for a set $V' \subseteq V$ such that every vertex is either an element of $V'$ or has a neighbor in $V'$, then what you're looking for is a [dominating set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominating_set).

---

In either case, the problem of finding the smallest such set is a well-known NP-complete problem, so there are no efficient algorithms for doing it exactly, although approximation algorithms are known.